# Bootstrap not able to stack text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm still learning Bootstrap 4 so there might be a class I don't that I should be using but I'm trying to get some text to stack on top of each other and cant get it to work.

I have a row above my NavBar with the logo to the left and the employee name/number/security group to the far right. What I'm trying to do is have the employee name - employee number and then below that have the group they are in.

I've tried several things from putting the security group in a `<div>` to using a `<br />` and `<p>` to try to get them to stack but with no luck.

I'm using flex box (which I don't completely understand just yet) so that I can get the employee info to align to the bottom of the row since the logo is tall compared to the text.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the text in the right column to stack short of using a table which I can do if that's my only option?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
                <img class="header-logo" src="~/images/logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
            <span>@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString()</span> -
            <span class="header-employee-id">@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString()</span>
            <p>@HttpContext.Current.Session["SecurityGroup"].ToString()</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `flex-column`. I assume you want the user spans together so those would get wrapped in a div.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href=")">
                <img class="header-logo" src="~/images/logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end flex-column">
            <div><span>UserName</span> - <span class="header-employee-id">UserId</span></div>
            <p>SecurityGroup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks. I need to find something that will go into more detail with Flexbox. I still don't have my head wrapped around that one just yet.

Comment: @Caverman Make sure to also check the Bootstrap flex docs. It provides a few good examples as well :) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/